# The Google Play Services Advertising Id API was called from a non-background thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to load Ad with Amazon mobile ads sdk. I call loadAd() method in asynctask , but the log shows 
" E/AmazonMobileAds GooglePlayServicesAdapter(9408): The Google Play Services Advertising Id API was called from a non-background thread.
" .

The code is :

```
//in class AdsManager
        public static void loadAd() { 
            new AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    mAdView.loadAd();
                    return null;
                }

            }.execute();
    }
```

In activity's     `onCreateView()`     , I set appId, and call             `AdsManager.loadAd()`

Thanks in advance

Comment: call it from main thread.

Comment: when we call it from main thread it shows the same

Comment: don't use async its meaningless. try to call it from onCreate and see if it works